# Node.js check value in a few redis sets and return synchronously

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, redis, node-redis

I have 7 sets and I need to check if value exists (`sismember`) at least in one set and return true or false.

I need to get that value synchronously, like this:

```
const isExist = !!(_.max(_.range(7).map((day) => {
    redis.sismember(`blacklist${day}`, hashToken, function (err, res) {
       return res;
    });
})));
```

Comment: You could run the query redis-side with lua scripts?

Comment: @ChrisTanner No, sorry, I can't. I need to do it on node.js server.

Comment: Instead of doing 7 roundtrips to redis, consider using lua script which can do this operation atomically.  This way you are sure that your checking operation is not interrupted by any other client code.

Comment: You can write a lua script and call it through nodeJS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never want synchronous code when you can avoid it.

In this case I would recommend to use Promises in order to manage the seven requests to redis.

The [Bluebird promise library](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/) can make most APIs promise-compatible in one line of code (read about [promisification](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promisification.html)), the API of redis is no exception. (The documentation of Bluebird even [uses redis as an example](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.promisifyall.html), and so does the [node-redis documentation](https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis#promises), so it's even "officially supported", if you care for that kind of thing.)

So what you seem to want is a function that checks up to seven asynchronous calls to `sismember` and resolves to an overal positive result as soon as the first of them has a positive result - [Promise#any()](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.any.html) can do that.

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var _ = require('lodash');
var redis = require('redis');

Promise.promisifyAll(redis);

function checkBlacklist(hashToken) {
    var blacklistChecks = _.range(7).map((day) => {
        return redis.sismemberAsync(`blacklist${day}`, hashToken);
    });
    return Promise.any(blacklistChecks);
}
```

usage

```
checkBlacklist('some_token').then((result) => {
   // do something with the result
}).catch((err) => {
   // an error has occurred - handle it or rethrow it
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If multiple redis ops are involved, generally I prefer to write lua script and then call it through my nodejs program.  This is an unrelated example, but it shows how you can use lua through nodejs.

example: get_state.lua

```
local jobId = KEYS[1]
local jobExists = redis.pcall('exists', jobId)
if jobExists == 0 or jobExists == nil then
  return 404  -- not found.
end

-- check the job state
local st = tonumber(redis.pcall('hmget', jobId, 'ctlState')[1])
if st == nil then
  st = 12002  -- job running, unless explicitly stated otherwise
end
return st
```

NodeJS code that uses lua: say index.js

```
...
// List of script files 
var scriptMap = { 
  getState: {file:'./scripts/get_state.lua'}
};


...

// A function to load the script file to Redis and cache the sha.
function loadScript(script) {
  logger.trace("loadScript(): executing...");
  if (scriptMap[script]['hash']) {
    logger.trace("Sript already loaded. Returning without loading again...");
    return Promise.resolve(scriptMap[script]['hash']);
  }

  //load from file and send to redis
  logger.trace("Loading script from file %s...", scriptMap[script].file);
  return fs.readFileAsync(scriptMap[script].file).then(function(data) {
    return getConnection().then(function(conn) {
      logger.trace("Loading script to Redis...");
      return conn.scriptAsync('load', data)
    })
  })
}
```

And, finally, a function that uses the cached sha digest to execute the script:

```
getJobState: function(jobId) {
    return loadScript('getState').then(function(hash) {
      return getConnection().then(function (conn) {
        return conn.evalshaAsync(hash, 1, jobId)
      })
    })
  },
```